# How can I unit test using a Qt spontaneous close event?

Tags: c++, qt, events

I have disabled the close button on some of the dialogs in my C++ Qt application. I am filtering based on whether or not the event is spontaneous and this works. My question however is about how to unit test this functionality. I would like to send both spontaneous and non spontaneous events to my unit under test to see that it reacts accordingly, I have found no way of injecting spontaneous events programmatically however. Does anyone know how this can be done? Or can you recommend other testing strategies in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [QCoreApplicationPrivate::setEventSpontaneous()](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/include/qt/QtCore/5.10.1/QtCore/private/qcoreapplication_p.h.html#_ZN23QCoreApplicationPrivate19setEventSpontaneousEP6QEventb) for this. You need to include the private `qcoreapplication_p.h` header, see e.g. [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/61967/add-qtgui-private-headers/4) on how to do that.

Alternatively, use the following, as long as you use widgets, as this is part of the Qt5Widgets library:

```
extern bool qt_sendSpontaneousEvent(QObject*, QEvent*);
```